# Using both explicit arguments and **kwargs in python

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
kwargs_input = {"name": "lala", "age": 25, "postcode": 17867}

def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print(k,v)

def func_print(name="lolo", age=56, **kwargs):
    print_kwargs(**kwargs)

print(func_print(**kwargs_input))
```

It prints:

```
postcode 17867
None
```

I have two questions:

1. Why `name` and `age` are not printed? I was expecting to override the default value of name (`lolo`) and age (`56`) with the arguments passed as `**kwargs_input`. Is that possible?
2. Where does `None` come from?

Answer (score 9):

1. Neither `name` nor `age` are printed, because they have been removed from `kwargs` during the function call. Inside the function call you have access to both `name` and `age` through those variables. `kwargs` will contain the rest of the 'variables'.
2. The `None` is returned from `func_print()` by default and your `print(func_print())` prints it out.

Comment: What can I do to make `kwargs` have default value? For example, if I don't set `name` in `kwargs_input`, I want `kwargs` to take the default value which is `lolo`.

Comment: You can add: `kwargs['name'] = name` inside the function (etc for each parameter with a default) to update `kwargs` with all the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`name` and `age` aren't packed into the first `kwargs` in `func_print()` therefore aren't passed further into other functions. Or in other words, it's not collecting **all** arguments, it's only collecting arguments that are unspecified, "dangling", so that it doesn't throw an error. Similar to [Varargs in C](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20512/14000).

`None` comes from the `func_print()`'s return as it's the default value of any function.

For example:

```py
def func():
    ...  # check help(...) and type(...)
    # implicit "return None"

def func():
    pass
    # implicit "return None"

def func():
    return
    # implicit "return None"

def func():
    # explicit return None
    return None
```

What you can however do is something that's common in JavaScript nowadays, send an object as an argument. Fortunately, you don't need to create and pass a custom object instance or anything like that because just `**kwargs` itself is a syntax that creates a dictionary (alternatively `*args` creates a `tuple`), so an object's instance preserving the arguments. (Similarly, you can use `*args` for positional arguments, [more on that here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)).

From that you can do this:

```py
def other(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs.get("name", "lolo"))
    other(**kwargs)

print(func(name=123, hello="world"))
# 123
# {'name': 123, 'hello': 'world'}
# None
print(func(hello="world"))
# lolo
# {'hello': 'world'}
# None
```

Answer (score 0):

Key here is that `**dict` in python unrolls the dict to key value pairs in the function call.

```py
kwargs_input = {"name": "lala", "age": 25, "postcode": 17867}

def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print(k,v)

def func_print(name="lolo", age=56, **kwargs):
    print_kwargs(**kwargs)

# Equivalent to passing **kwargs_input
print(func_print(name='lala', age=25, postcode=17867))
```

`**kwargs` then captures all those 'extra' key word arguments not specified in the function definiton.

As you can see `name` and `age` are.